# yii-user extension include(WebUser.php) No such file or directory

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

i'm trying to install the extension of yii-user following this official tutorial

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/#hh2

But i'm having some problems, specially when i'm adding this

```
 user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'class' => 'WebUser',
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        'loginUrl' => array('/user/login'),
```

to the configuration main. When i add this code, i have this message error

**include(WebUser.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

Any clue? I need to do something before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched a little bit and i found the solution. But it wasn't in the documentation.

So, we should create the **WebUser.php** in **protected/components** like this :

```
  <?php

// this file must be stored in:
// protected/components/WebUser.php

class WebUser extends CWebUser {

// Store model to not repeat query.
 private $UserLogin;

// Return first name.
// access it by Yii::app()->user->first_name
function getFirst_Name(){
$user = $this->loadUserLogin(Yii::app()->user->user_id);
return $user->first_name;
}  

// This is a function that checks the field 'role'
// in the User model to be equal to 1, that means it's admin
// access it by Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()
function isAdmin(){
$user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->user_id);
return intval($user->user_role_id) == 1;
}

// Load user model.
protected function loadUserLogin($id=null)
{
    if($this->UserLogin===null)
    {
        if($id!==null)
            $this->UserLogin=UserLogin::model()->findByPk($id);
    }
    return $this->UserLogin;
}
}?>
```

and should work.

Comment: If you are trying to install the yii-user extension, you should not create your own WebUser class. It is already included in the extension under user/components.

Comment: The .rar that i have downloaded doesn't have one. But thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the instructions at http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/#hh2?

You probably forgot to specify import paths to the user module in `config.php`

```
'import'=>array(
    ...
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that it's the permission problem. Apache user (www-data in my case) couldn't access protected/modules/users/* files.